# Lua split string into 2d array in single step

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have the following string

```
abc=1.2;bcd=2.4;xyz=10.9
```

I want to split it into the following table

```
{ {"abc", "1.2}, {"bcd", "2.4"}, {"xyz", "10.9"} }
```

I am currently doing this by splitting the strings first by `;` and then by `=`.

In PHP I can use the following `preg_match` pattern to do this in a single step without iteration. Is it possible to do this in Lua?

```
preg_match_all("/(?:([a-z]+)=([0-9.]+)(?:;|$))/", $a, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
s="abc=1.2;bcd=2.4;xyz=10.9"

s=s..";"
t={}
for k,v in s:gmatch("(.-)=(.-);") do
    t[#t+1]={k,v}
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This is much better than my current solution.

Comment: Currently I am using `table.insert(t, {k, v})`. Is `t[#t+1]={k,v}` preferred over `table.insert`?

Comment: @JoyceBabu, `table.insert` is fine.